# Examples of Dust.js templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, dust.js

I try to find difficult examples of large web applications based on Node.js + Dust.js as a template engine.

At the best case it will be LinkedIn source code of templates ;)

Comment: Maybe this could be useful https://github.com/sourcefabric/Superdesk/tree/master/plugins/livedesk-embed/gui-themes/themes

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of node applications shown as examples of using KrakenJS. Look through them for examples of using dust with Node.js.

http://krakenjs.com/#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Try this some node and dust example:

http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html

Comment: Please prefer inline content over link-only answers. Also, I would not personally feed off-topic questions with answers. It shows them they are much appreciated on the site, whereas it is probably better to ask elsewhere than Stack Overflow proper.